# Google Reader widget items blinking

Tags: app-widgets, google-reader

I have both a smartphone (Motorola Defy/MB525 running CyanogenMod 9) and a tablet (a cheap "generic" Genesis GT1230 running some obscure custom ROM). When I add the Google Reader widget (official app), after some time the items in the widget start blinking (not the widget itself, just the entries in the widget). Same issue on both devices. I have not been able to identify a cause, let alone find a solution. Any advices?

Comment: Strangely enough, this issue seems to appear and disappear randomly over time, and I'm still unable to determine a possible cause or suspect. I have for, the time being, given up on using the Reader widget, but plan to inspect more in the future.

Comment: As [Google Reader has been discontinued](http://www.google.com/reader/about/), this question is now obsolete.